# Capitalized i when using ###?

Tags: discussion, markdown, editor

Someone edited [my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129191/overloaded-applyrestrictionstocriteria-methods) to change

```
**Some text containing an i**
```

to

```
### Some text containing an i
```

Which is completely fine.
However, I noticed that when using `###` the `i`'s are being capitalized. Is there a reason for this, because it looks a bit odd to me personally..

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]